# Breadcrumbs Express

Tags: node.js, express, breadcrumbs

I'd like to show Breadcrumbs for my pages in express. I couldn't find much and it seems like there are only a few people who want to build breadcrumbs on their websites or there must be a completely different way to solve the issue. I found 2-3 middlewares which are not actively maintained and it seems they doesn't support dynamic routes or it's not documentated well.

So assuming I got the following routes and breadcrumb names:

- / => "Home"
- /projects => "Projects"
- /projects/:id/:slug => "Projectname from DB"
- /projects/manage => "Manage"

I expected a popular middleware which is capable of storing breadcrumbs dynamically and once I call a "subpage" it will list return all parent breadcrumbs too. Something like this:

```
router.get('/:id/:slug', function(req, res, next) {
    var projectName = 'John Doe Project';
    req.breadcrumbs().add({name: projectName, url: '/url/to/project/'});
    res.render('projects/index', { title: 'Express', breadcrumbs: req.breadcrumbs()});
});
```

What is the best practice for providing breadcrumbs?

Comment: What was wrong with https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-breadcrumbs

Comment: @hjpotter92 it didn't add the parent's breadcrumbs automatically. I am not sure if it's supposed to do so, but it seems like I need to add all the desired breadcrumbs for each route manually.

Comment: Is there a reason can't you parse the route yourself and render crumbs based on the parts?

Comment: Well I could, but 1. I don't want add all URL parts into my breadcrumb and 2. Each part should have a breadcrumb name. Hence I thought I'd rather ask how others are handling breadcrumbs